# Why did Ozzy Osborne choose to make "Hero" a hidden track?

Tags: rock, metal, hidden-track

When the album "No Rest For The Wicked" was released adding extra "hidden" tracks to the end of albums was the latest "thing." They are usually either an outtake or a song that doesn't fit stylistically with the album, thus they're are usually attached to the end of the final "official" track after a long space.

In this case, though, there is only a short space after the last "official" song, and the song that is "hidden" and uncredited is easily the best song on the album (imho). Without it the album is only 38:19 long, which is fairly short for a cd. And *Hero* makes a great album ender, whereas *Demon Alcohol* is not a very good closing track.

Additionally, it is more radio-friendly than any of the tracks that were released as singles. It is very accessible, yet it's still very Ozzy. But putting it at the end of another track virtually ensured it could get no radio play. Sometimes rock stations will pick non-single tracks from an album if they think it's worth playing. But in 1988 most radio stations were playing CD's, and unless they were given a single from the label they would be unlikely to spend the time to cue up a "hidden" track.

All of this makes me wonder if the producer or any of the musicians has ever spoken about why they chose to put such a good song as an Easter egg.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the [wikipedia entry about the 'No rest for the Wicked tour'](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/No_Rest_for_the_Wicked_Tour) the song did not feature on the tour.

On a [fan website](https://songmeanings.com/songs/view/85339/), "ysis2" offers this explanation

> I think this song kinda correlated to the John McCollum suicide
> lawsuit brought against Ozzy around 1987 (Another similar situation
> around this time occurred with Judas Priest where they were being sued
> after 2 young men killed themselves listening to their music). The
> trial was going on probably about the time Ozzy was making the No Rest
> For The Wicked album (this song was originally hidden on this
> album).... I think this was a hidden bonus track because they probably
> weren't sure how it would be received by his fans following the
> outcome of the trial (around that time). I think it was included on
> the album to kinda remind fans to enjoy his music, but don't be
> foolish enough to think he's all so powerful. Plus, I think it was to
> ensure no other fans in the future would misinterpret his music in
> such a drastic way. He really doesn't wanna be directly responsible
> for the lives (or deaths) of his fans.

the John Mccollum lawsuit was filed in 1985 by John's parents, on the basis that John had died as a result of following the lyrics of the Black Sabbath song "Suicide Solution". The lawsuit was dismissed in 1988, and in later years, Ozzy said that the song was about the alcohol-related death of Bon Scott of AC/DC in 1980
[NME interview](https://www.nme.com/news/music/ozzy-osbourne-says-his-song-suicide-solution-was-misunderstood-2755508)

> Now, as the 40th anniversary of Osbourne’s album this month nears, the
> Prince of Darkness has cleared up what he says is a common
> misunderstanding. The song is in fact an anti-suicide composition
> written about AC/DC singer Bon Scott, who died of acute alcohol
> poisoning in 1980.

The explanation certainly fits the timeline, and is believable.  In the absence of any definite statement from Ozzy, that's probably the best explanation for now, until any new information turns up.